# Processing Error: badly formed character constant (expecting quote, got h)

Tags: java, processing

I'm making a virtual pet game. At this stage I have loading a save file working, but the program is not running when I start to include core functionality.

I found this: [Badly formed character (expecting quote, got I) ~ Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446501/badly-formed-character-expecting-quote-got-i-processing)
Which leads me to think that it is an issue with my load function, but I am new to Processing and am not sure how to debug this.

```
Creature creature;
String data[];
boolean gameInfo[];
int tempData[];
boolean food;

void setup() {
  size(100,100);
  String data[] = loadStrings("save.txt");
  String[] tempData = split(data[0], ',');
  gameInfo = int(tempData);
  for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    creature = new Creature(gameInfo[0], gameInfo[1], gameInfo[2], gameInfo[3]);
  }
  food = false;
}

void draw() {
  creature.think(food);
}

//creature class

class Creature {
  boolean idle;
  int hungry;
  int age;
  int gender;
  int asleep;


  Creature(int gender, int age, int hungry, int asleep) {
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
    this.hungry = hungry;
    this.asleep = asleep;
    boolean idle = true;
  }
  void whatDo(boolean food) {
    println('whatdo');
    if (idle = true && hungry == true) {
      if (food == true) {
        creature.eat();
      }
      else 
        creature.ask();
    }
  }

  void ask() {
    if (hungry == true) {
      println("HUNGRY");
    }
  }
  void eat() {
    println("EAT");
    idle = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: In line `if (idle = true && hungry == true)` you probably meant `idle==true`, didn't you?

Comment: yeah, noticed that the second I posted it, it's changed now.
Thanks nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as the link you pointed explains, the problem is that single quote is for characters assignment so it shoud be a character between two single quotes, like `'c'`, and println() expects a string wich is defined between double quotes `"a string"`. Just replace `println('whatdo');` in line 40 with `println("whatdo");` (double quotes) and you get rid of this error. But i got others errors after fixing that though.

Comment: If you are interested to see how the program has developed, I've posted again here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015560/get-value-from-an-arraylist-of-objects-processing.